# select max of date with query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, timestamp

I want to select max of date in hibernate but I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER

The query is :

```
select   coalesce(max (rc.dateTransactionReceipt),0  ) from MAMReceiptTransactions rc where   rc.mamItems.id =m.id ) as lastDateOfCharge
```

and the database is oracle.
 Type of this field in database is TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Why would you want to return 0 if the timestamp was null? Null itself sounds reasonable than that.. Perhaps SYSTIMESTAMP if you want current timestamp..

Comment: yes, you are right. plz add your answer to accept it...Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get `0` when timestamp doesn't make sense apart from being syntactically incorrect (The datatypes of the coalesce parameters must be compatible). Null itself sounds reasonable.

```
select max(rc.dateTransaction) from your_table rc
```

If you want to have a default timestamp returned, you can use that in the coalesce instead. Perhaps you want current timestamp returned in case the above returns null.

```
select coalesce(max(rc.dateTransaction), systimestamp) from your_table rc;
```